# How to change languages dynamically with react-redux-i18n

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, multilingual, i18next

I use https://github.com/artisavotins/react-redux-i18n to try to create the easy switching language feature. The user can use drop down, and I have add I18n into the app reducer.  [image]

In different UI component's renders, I use `<Translate/> or I18n.t` to convert ids to strings. But in fact the both ways cannot change the translation correctly even if I correctly setLocale to the I18n. Should I set I18n to be a state of the Ui components? Any advices to this issue are appreciated.

The I18n object looks like something bellow,
[image]